# Temperature below which Quantum Mechanical effects become relevant

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, partition-function

A question was asked last year in Phd qualifiying exam, the first part was finding partition function which is simple but other two parts are bit confusing I would be pleased if you can help:

A particle is subjected to the potential:

$$
V(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{2}\ mw^{2}z^{2}\     
 \textrm{if}\ 
\ \ 0<x<L \ \ \textrm{and}\quad 0<y<L
\  
$$
$$
V(x,y,z) = \infty \quad otherwise
$$

Which means it is free to move in the xy plane within square of area L^2 and subject to a harmonic potential along z direction.

Below which temperature Tz quantum mechanical effects become relevant in the z direction?

Below which temperature Txy quantum mechanical effects become relevant in the xy plane?

Comment: You can get the answer from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_de_Broglie_wavelength. Basically from the thermal de Broglie wavelength.